# How to make credit card (xxxx-xxxx-xxxx) type text in swift

Tags: swift2

I am trying to create credit card type text with following code, but not able to do that, is there any way to do?

```
func textField(textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersInRange range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool {
    let formatter = NSNumberFormatter()

    formatter.groupingSize = 4
    formatter.groupingSeparator = "-"
    formatter.usesGroupingSeparator = true

    print("txtCardNumber \(txtCardNumber.text)")
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Formatting a UITextField for credit card input like (xxxx xxxx xxxx xxxx)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12083605/formatting-a-uitextfield-for-credit-card-input-like-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx)

Comment: Its not duplicate as this answer is in objective-c language with some lengthy logic..i am trying to do in swift with standard logic

Comment: The question has Swift answers, too. Googleing your question title brings up more good results. You may have to rewrite them a little bit but what's out there looks really reasonable.

Comment: @Pekka웃 Yes you are right, Thank you :)

Answer (score 22):

Below logic implements simple 16 digits credit card formatting with spaces.

**Edit: Code adjusted for Swift 4/5**

Step 1: Create an action for for credit card textfield

```
self.txtFieldCreditCardNumber.addTarget(self, action: #selector(didChangeText(textField:)), for: .editingChanged)
```

Step 2: Call a method from this selector method of textfield that will do the formatting

```
@objc func didChangeText(textField:UITextField) {
    textField.text = self.modifyCreditCardString(creditCardString: textField.text!)
}
```

Step 3: Implement the method "modifyCreditCardString"

```
func modifyCreditCardString(creditCardString : String) -> String {
     let trimmedString = creditCardString.components(separatedBy: .whitespaces).joined()

     let arrOfCharacters = Array(trimmedString)
     var modifiedCreditCardString = ""

     if(arrOfCharacters.count > 0) {
         for i in 0...arrOfCharacters.count-1 {
             modifiedCreditCardString.append(arrOfCharacters[i])
             if((i+1) % 4 == 0 && i+1 != arrOfCharacters.count){
                 modifiedCreditCardString.append(" ")
             }
         }
     }
     return modifiedCreditCardString
 }
```

Step 4: Implement the delegate of UITextField, which will restrict the card numbers to 16 characters. 19 = 16 + 3 (1 spaces after each 4 digits)

```
func textField(_ textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersIn range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool {
     let newLength = (textField.text ?? "").count + string.count - range.length
     if(textField == txtFieldCreditCardNumber) {
         return newLength <= 19
     }
     return true
}
```

Hope this will help. Thanks

Comment: Good job, very well written!

Comment: how to enter 9 digits in textfield like XXX-XXXXXX in swift